# Autostart a graphical application in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: autostart

I want an application to get opened after any user is logged in. I read about some menu about autostart. etc. But, unfortunately I don't have GUI access now. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do you know about the 'startx' command and the 'gksudo' command?

Comment: No.. I just want to start an application when a user a logged in. For eg. gimp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place one or more desktop files in

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/
```

for a system wide configuration.

---

Eg:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/gimp.desktop
```

To delay the start, replace the `Exec` property with eg

```
sh -c "sleep 20; gimp"
```